# How to open this in new tab via php?

Tags: php, html, css

How can I open this in new tab via php?

[image]

I tried to open this cart and wish list page in a new tab but its showing a blank page,

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'businessbloomer_add_target_blank', 10, 2 );
 
function businessbloomer_add_target_blank( $product, $args ){
 
$link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
        isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
);
 
return $link;
 
}
```

this is the example link... http://hero.woxear.com/

Comment: I think you should try to reverse the quotes

Comment: May be try target=“_new” instead of blank.

Comment: Those links with the `data-quantity` attribute are the (+) links on the product cards, to add a product to the cart. Your screenshot indicates that you want to manipulate the shopping cart and wishlist icon in the header, so this is the wrong hook to begin with (clue kinda in the name here.) And if you actually inspect those icons, you see that the links around them are of the form `<a href="javascript:void(0);"` - those aren’t “real” links, but just have onclick behavior added from the JavaScript somewhere, so trying to add a target attribute would be pointless to begin with.

Comment: "its showing a blank page" -> check your error logs; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851